# I would like to develop application for iPhone and Android. Which framework it is better to use?

Tags: java, iphone, android, flash

I would like to develop applications for iPhone and Android devices. Which language it is better to use Java or Flash?
I have read that Adobe Flash CSS 5.5 support compatibility for ActionScript on both devices. Will be interesting to know plus and minus sides for both languages? 
Remember that we have to develop application for both devices, and we have a small part of that application already written in Java.

Comment: What skillsets do you have?  What are your requirements?  If you want what is "best", you'd use Java + Android SDK on Android, and Objective-C + Cocoa Touch on iOS.

Comment: Perhaps [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) could be an option

Answer (score 2):

[Titanium by Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com),
A superb tool to develop apps for all major Mobile Computing platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You could get yourself a [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) license and write your App in .NET, for deployment on both iOS, Android and Windows Mobile. It's not quite cheap though.